# Oracle SQL-Updating Rows with Another Table Key

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, where-clause, dml

I am using SQL developer

I am writing code to update several columns.

I have many ID column in two tables and department columns.

I want to change table 1 columns value.

```
update table1 a
set a.key_ıd = (case 
                   when a.key_ıd = 1 then 101
                   when a.key_ıd = 2 then 102
                   .
                   .
                   else a.ıd 
                end)
from table1 a, table2 b
where a.ıd = b.ıd
  and b.key_ıd in (1, 2, ...)
  and b.type <> 2;
```

But from line getting red, any suggestions?

> Error at Command Line : 5 Column : 1
> Error report -
> SQL Error: ORA-00933:
> 00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

I don't understand why this code doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using a `MERGE` Statement with `WHEN MATCHED` option such as

```
MERGE INTO table1 t1
USING ( SELECT *
          FROM table2 t ) t2
   ON ( t1.id = t2.id AND t2.type <> 2 AND t2.key_id IN (1,2...) )                 
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t1.key_id = CASE WHEN t1.key_id = t2.key_id THEN
                                                    t1.key_id + 100
                                               ELSE
                                                    t1.id
                                                END
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=eb4b0edb101a98ddb99b9ed769e95068)</kbd>

- `UPDATE .. SET ... FROM..` syntax is not supported within Oracle DB unlike to some other well-known DBM Systems
- The former Join syntax containing comma-seperated tables shouldn't be
  used rather the SQL-92 syntax with explicit `JOIN` keywords should be
  preferred as being easier to use whenever a Join statement is needed

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `exists`:

```
UPDATE table1 a
    SET a.key_ıd = (CASE WHEN a.key_ıd=1 THEN 101
                         WHEN a.key_ıd=2 THEN 102
                                       .
                                       .
                         ELSE a.ıd
                    END)
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table2 b
                  WHERE a.ıd = b.ıd AND
                        b.key_ıd IN (1,2,...) AND
                        b.type <> 2
                  );
```

Oracle doesn't support a `FROM` clause in `UPDATE`.  And the logic for setting the new values only uses the table being updated.  So, you just want to filter the rows that are affected.  For this `EXISTS` is a suitable approach.